# MySQL + PHP обновление/добавление записей в БД SELECT + UPDATE/INSERT = дубликаты

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть некий кусок кода для обновления/добавления записи в БД который выбирает запись из БД SELECT-ом, и если она есть - делает UPDATE, если нет - INSERT.

Проблема в следующем: если зафлудить скрипт (вызвать через мерную нагрузку), то начинают появляться дубликаты записей.
Т.е. как я понимаю, SELECT-ы как-то группируются и кэшируются что-ли?

Кто может объяснить такое поведение?

Понятно, что добавив уникальное значение в таблицу, можно избежать дубликаты, но по Т.З. уникальным полем для обновления данных - может выступать любое поле в ходе обращения к скрипту.

Данная проблема возникла на конкретном рабочем проекте, но для теста я смог ее воспроизвести в помощью скрипта: https://pastebin.com/BjR8tXzC и ab-тестером:

```
ab -n 1000 -c 10 http://site.com/test-overload.php
```

Тестовая таблица (SHOW CREATE TABLE `test_overload`;):

```
CREATE TABLE `test_overload` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `code` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `data` text NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Возможно ли как-то изменить поведение, чтоб не появлялись дубликаты? (кроме INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...)
Может настройка MySQL ?

Comment: а может не в кешировании дело, а в том, что между селектом и инсертом одного скрипта успевает проскочить селект второго скрипта (который тоже не увидел записи, т.к. первый ее не успел создать)?

Comment: уникальный составной индекс/поле ?

Comment: Делайте выборку и последующее обновление / вставку в транзакции. Тогда не будет таких проблем, если не можете сделать уникальным полем составной ключ.

Comment: @AlexandrX, думаю Ваша теория в качестве ответа на вопрос "Почему?" вполне походит. Спасибо! :)

Comment: *Возможно ли как-то изменить поведение, чтоб не появлялись дубликаты? (кроме INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...)* Да. Есть изолирующие транзакции. Есть SELECT ... FOR UPDATE. Есть LOCK TABLES. Но для озвученной задачи ODKU и транзакции - решение, а всё остальное - костыли.

Comment: @Akina, можете подсказать как модифицировать код, чтоб запихнуть запросы в транзакцию? Я попробовал вот так: https://pastebin.com/hMFWUKSF , но это не помогло... все равно появляются дубликаты. ENGINE=MyISAM.

Comment: *ENGINE=MyISAM* MyISAM не знает про существование транзакций.